# Angular - TS - Error TS1109: Expression Expected

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and trying one of the tutorial from 'Traversy Media' on YouYube.

I am trying to create a user component and then fetch posts from a link, but when I am running the code it is giving me Error TS1109: Expression Expected

**ERROR**

```
src/app/services/posts.service.ts(12,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

**CODE** that I am using

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService{
  constructor(private http: Http){
   console.log('PostsService Initialized...');
 }

getPosts(){
    return.this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Please do forgive me if I have done a blunder as I am new to this technology.

Comment: Just FYI ... "Angular" is now used for Angular v2 and above. "AngularJS" is for Angular v1. Using the correct terms and tags will help ensure your question gets reviewed by the devs that could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the . after return

```
  getPosts(){
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .map(res => res.json());
      }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that was really a blunder

Answer (score 1):

This part: `return.this` needs to have a space and not a dot: `return this`